# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException:Closed Connection

Tags: java, jboss, oracle11gr1

I am using jboss7.0.2 final with Oracle 11. Currently I am facing one issue which happens randomly. But during heavy load this error trace keeps growing. Tried so many approaches couldn't succeed.

**MyDatasource Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasource jndi-name="sportPool" pool-name="sportPool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.11.252.200:1521:sportsdb</connection-url>
    <driver>oracleDriver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>75</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>mportal</user-name>
        <password>mobile</password>
    </security>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>60000</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

**StackTrace:**

```
nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.translate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:82)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:237)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:604)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:638)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:683)

        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.ensureOpen(OracleStatement.java:4051)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3563)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:111)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:645)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:588)
        ... 56 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick update on how I fixed this issue.
I've done following changes outside of the application i.e in JBOSS

```
**ironjacamar-jdbc**
```

1. Updateed ironjacamar-jdbc jar from 1.0.3 to 1.1.0 at this location "{JBOSS_HOME_7.0.2}/modules/org/jboss/ironjacamar/jdbcadapters/main/"

   **`Stanalone.xml`**

As suggested by npe added `<check-valid-connection-sql>`.

```
<datasource jndi-name="sportPool" pool-name="sptPool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.11.252.200:1521:sprtsdb
    </connection-url>
    <driver>
        oracleDriver
    </driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>90</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>mtal</user-name>
        <password>mle</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

This solved the problem. But jboss prints warning message "IJ000612" in console which I think should be ok as long as application is getting valid connection object from jboss.

Answer (score 5):

1. Take a look at your database settings - it's possible, that the timeout set in database is shorter than the timeout set in datasource deployment descriptor, and the database closes the connections.
2. Check your network - it's possible that there is something wrong with your firewall / routing settings, and the connections are closed/dropped somewhere in the middle of the route.
3. Take a look at this link [JBoss 7 Datasource Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/userguide/1.0/en-US/html/deployment.html#d0e2292). There is a way of configuring a datasource descriptor, forcing the JBoss to check the connection when checking it out from the pool. Use the `valid-connection-checker` (faster) or `check-valid-connection-sql` (slower) setting and set the

   ```
   <valid-connection-checker>
       org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker
   </valid-connection-checker>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <check-valid-connection-sql>
       SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
   </check-valid-connection-sql>
   ```

Comment: 1. I don't how to check the timeout on database server. But on

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here are my answers to your points. 1. I don't know how to check the timeout on database server but on server i changed the idle timeout to 15mins. 2. There are no network issues as i tried so many instances. 3. I configured <check-valid-connection-sql> and restarted server, still throws same error.

Comment: I'd also check, whether the connection is manually closed somewhere in code. If `valid-connection-checker` does not help, then it means, that the connection is closed _after_ checking it out from the pool.

Comment: So, what approach i should to fix this issue?

Comment: A quick update for this issue. I've done following changes outside of the application - 1. Updateed ironjacamar-jdbc jar from 1.0.3 to 1.1.0 and as suggested by npe added <check-valid-connection-sql> . This solved the problem. But jboss prints warning message "IJ000612" in console which i think should be ok as long as application is getting valid connection object from jboss.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your are losing connection, in most cases this happens when there network problems. The configuration you are using is a bit strange;

```
idle-timeout-minutes = 41 days , default is 15 minutes
min-pool-size = 1
```

probably the  idle-timeout-minutes causing your SQLRecoverableExceptions,  I would use a config like;

```
idle-timeout-minutes = 15 minutes
min-pool-size = 10
max-pool-size = 50 or even less You are using 150MB memory for 75 connections
```

if you don't have long blocking connection to the database 20 max pool size should be enough.

Comment: by the way the java.sql.SQLRecoverableException will probably give functional no problem to the end user

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your settings. Still running into same issue.

Comment: The stacktrace is caused by connection problems, in most cases this caused by bad switches, bad host files, bad infra shared production network